# Implement JWT authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, jwt

I am looking for the easiest way to implement JSON Web Token authentication using `IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`. Here is a link to a package itself:

[JSON Web Token Handler For the Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5 4.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)

Comment: What's the specific issue you are having?

Comment: My specific issue is lack of documentation and guide that shows how to use classes from this package

Comment: +1 on the sparse doc of MS package. That said, you may find [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JWT) much easier to use/customize to your needs. The [project site](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt) will give you all the details. Hth..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
var securityKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("MySecretKey"));
var header = new JwtHeader(new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest));
var payload = new JwtPayload();

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "jdoe@gmail.com"),
    ...
};

payload.AddClaims(claims);

// if you need something more complex than string/string data
payload.Add("tags", new List<string> { "admin", "user" });

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
var tokenString = securityTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```